# Mailchimp RSS campaign only includes 1 post

Tags: wordpress, rss, mailchimp

Setting up an RSS campaign with Mailchimp, and hit a roadblock. The import seems to work, the design looks great, but we only are able to ever get one post -- the most recent one-- into the email.

The RSS feed is:  https://our.news/feed/trending

We have verified that pubDate is included and properly formatted on all items, ie:

```
<item>
    <title>The FBI is warning you to reboot your router to prevent a new attack here&#8217;s everything you need to do</title>
    <link>https://our.news/2018/05/30/the-fbi-is-warning-you-to-reboot-your-router-to-prevent-a-new-attack-heres-everything-you-need-to-d/</link>
    <comments>https://our.news/2018/05/30/the-fbi-is-warning-you-to-reboot-your-router-to-prevent-a-new-attack-heres-everything-you-need-to-d/#comments</comments>
    <pubDate>Wed, 30 May 2018 07:33:04 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[OurBot]]></dc:creator>
            <category><![CDATA[Headlines]]></category>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">https://our.news/?p=103857</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[BUSINESSINSIDER.COM &#8211; On Friday, the FBI said anyone who uses a router to connect to the internet should reboot their routers. That will &#8220;temporarily disrupt...]]></description>
    <wfw:commentRss>https://our.news/2018/05/30/the-fbi-is-warning-you-to-reboot-your-router-to-prevent-a-new-attack-heres-everything-you-need-to-d/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
    <slash:comments>1</slash:comments>
    <media:content xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" medium="image" type="image/jpeg" url="https://dsezcyjr16rlz.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/30023303/httpsamp.businessinsider.comimages5b0d64001ae66220008b47d5640320.1.jpg.jpg" width="150" height="75" />    
</item>
```

The specific email design template we're using is simple, relevant section is:

```
*|RSSITEMS:[$count=5]|* 
<span style="float:left">*|RSSITEM:IMAGE|* </span> 
<a href="*|RSSITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*</a>
*|END:RSSITEMS|*
```

This happens in Preview Mode, in the Test Email, AND in the actual weekly campaign sends. The campaign is set to send weekly, and when it does, it only includes the first item from the list. Ideally, we'd like this to always just include the most recent 5 items. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a FeedBlock

```
*|FEEDBLOCK:https://www.url.com/test.xml|*

*|FEEDITEMS:[$count=5]|* 
<span style="float:left">*|FEEDITEM:IMAGE|* </span> 
<a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</a>

*|END:FEEDITEMS|*
```